# Excel search string in cells by mutiple words

Tags: vba, excel

I have a TextBox and ListBox. I want to find a string in a range containing specific multiple words (keywords) written in TextBox and display it in the ListBox

For example:

I have a string a = "Sun is shinning"
And I want to research the range, find and display cell value containing these specific words when I write in TextBox for example "sun shinning".
Take a look into my last string where I write word "sun" in lowercase.

I wrote the code

```
    Sub AAA()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("BBB")
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long


        ZZZ.Clear
        LastRow = ws.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        With ZZZ
            .ColumnCount = 3
            .ColumnWidths = "100;400"

            For i = 2 To LastRow
              '  For x = 0 To UBound(z)
                    If ws.Range("E" & i) Like AAA

.Value & "*" Then

                            .AddItem ws.Range("D" & i)
                            .column(1, ZZZ.ListCount - 1) = ws.Range("E" & i)
                            '.column(2, ZZZ.ListCount - 1) = ws.Range("E" & I)

                    End If
              '   Next x
            Next i

        End With

End Sub
```

But each time when I try to add second loop responsible for splitting the sentence and loop by each word I get an error message.

Have you got any idea how to simply modify my code to do that?

Comment: this is not c# related - please remove this, it is purely excel vba. It will also help people if you can make your question clearer, such as what error it is you're getting..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming multiple words entered into textbox AAA are always entered with spaces, this procedure works (**tried and tested**).

The procedure uses the `Split` function to load the word(s) in the AAA textbox into an array, then loops the array for each cell.

```
Sub AAA()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("BBB")
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long


        ZZZ.Clear
        LastRow = ws.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        With ZZZ

            .ColumnCount = 3
            .ColumnWidths = "100;400"

            For i = 2 To LastRow

                Dim sWords() As String, x As Integer

                sWords = Split(AAA.Value, " ")

                For x = 0 To UBound(sWords)

                    If ws.Range("E" & i) Like "*" & sWords(x) & "*" Then

                        .AddItem ws.Range("D" & i)
                        .Column(1, Sheet1.ZZZ.ListCount - 1) = ws.Range("E" & i)

                    End If

               Next x

            Next i

        End With

    End Sub
```

*As I type this I had the thought that it may be even faster to loop the array once and Find any matches of each word in the entire range, but I will leave that up to you.*

Comment: Unfortunetly i got an error. Argument is not optional in line with Split(AAA.value, " ") - I dont know why. I believe that is easy to fix but i can not find the solution

Comment: @wiecman -> you may need to qualify the `AAA` text box to the worksheet (using the vba object name ... `Sheet1` for example). I tested this code and it worked when I qualified the objects.

Comment: I use UserForm where i have TextBox and as an Object i set UserForm name Unfortunately without results - same error. Have you got maybe your tested file and you could share it with me ?

Comment: It works like a charm. I found the issue in other module.